# Фиксация столбца cxTableView

Tags: delphi, devexpress

Нужно зафиксировать по левому краю столбец cxDBGrid.cxTableView, что бы при скролинге он оставался по левому краю. Вьюха без бэндов.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете достичь этого, используя `Banded View`. Нужно создать два `band'a` и установить свойство одному из них `FixedKind := fkLeft` и параметр `Options.HoldOwnColumnsOnly := True`. Для колонки, которую нужно зафиксировать, установить свойство `Position.BandIndex` - индекс нужного `band'a`.

Подсмотрено [тут](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A553/is-it-possible-to-make-a-column-leftmost-and-prevent-other-columns-from-taking-this)

Comment: Спасибо. Меня интересует можно ли сделать такое в вьюхе без бэндов.